# Getting the log info on startup?

Tags: android

My app causes a force close on startup on certain devices. But I can't see a record of the force close because when I open logcat it seems to have missed it, like the crash happened before the log was been read. Is there a direct way to get to the log that will show me the error message?

Comment: Do you override the `onStart` or `onResume` and put log messages in those?

Comment: Do you have a filter on the log? The error message might not have your package name in it.

Comment: Do you see in the log the system launching the application?

Comment: No filter on. No message in onStart or onResume - I just checked. I can't actually see any reference to the application at all in the log. However once the initial force close is passed the app runs fine. I'm sure its something to do with the availability of the internet connection. I'll add some code to make sure it checks before it tries to send anything from the service threads.